# Why does it re-render when same value set-stating?

Tags: reactjs

[image]

Why this function component has so many re-renders error?

I know function component is checked with Object.is method, and then result is true does not re-render. So, why this error occur?

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-shape-26fmt3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please provide a [mre], and include the code **and** the error as code formatted text, not as screenshots.

Comment: [...Typically, this means that you’re unconditionally setting state during render, so your component enters a loop: render, set state (which causes a render), render, set state (which causes a render), and so on](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#im-getting-an-error-too-many-re-renders)

Comment: @AdamJenkins
Thanks to comment!
I understood maybe

so these component will always update, because there are no compare to re-render (cause set-state is below the return)
am i right to understand?

Answer (score 1):

Because when the state is updated, React components also get updated. Whenever a component updates, the state also updates, which leads to an infinite loop.

Comment: But state updating with same value (I knew same value seting-state will not cause update)
why leads to infinite loop?

Comment: @HyesungOh "I knew same value seting-state will not cause update" you knew incorrectly, it does update.

Comment: @HyesungOh You can use React Hooks to avoid component updates caused by the same value, such as useMemo, useCallback, and useEffect.

Comment: @Caleth but react docs said 'When state changes, the component responds by re-rendering.' 
https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do

Comment: @HyesungOh setting the values to an equivalent value is a change.

Comment: @Caleth Im sorry to ask. but why that is a change ?? I dont understand :C

Comment: That's how React defines change. Any call to `setNumber` is a change in the state, even if the value stays the same

Comment: @Caleth I can understand what your said with my heart, but do not understand with my brain :C
because The React docs said "state changes, the component responds by re-rendering'.
also https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-frog-t63zjx?file=/src/App.js same setting state does not call log below example.
Can you tell me about more specific?